# Httponly cookie not being set / stored (Laravel / Vue)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cookies, laravel-5.8

I have been struggling with this for a few hours now on how to solve this issue and I just can't seem to be able to get around it for now.

Am building a simple authentication system with a `Vue` front-end(created using `vue-cli`) and `Laravel 5.8`(api) for the backend; to test out the idea of using httponly cookie for authentication and protection of access to certain routes after reading [this](https://medium.com/@shindelav/make-an-api-based-application-with-laravel-passport-d6f1074a7b3a) article. I am using [tymondesigns/jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) for authentication instead of [laravel passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport) as used in the article and am also using [barryvdh/laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)
 package to add CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) headers support.

#### BACKEND

Here is my code in the `routes/api.php`

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth', 'namespace' => 'Auth'], function () {
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth.api'],], function () {
        Route::get('me', 'AuthController@me');
        Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
    });
});
```

And the code for the middleware that am using is as follows in the `app/Http/Kernel.php`

```php
'auth.api' => [
    \App\Http\Middleware\AddAuthTokenHeader::class,
    'throttle:60,1',
    'bindings',
    'auth:api',
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
],
```

And here is my code in the `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Authenticate user via given credentials.
     *
     * @param \App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest $request
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function login(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->all(['email', 'password']);

        if (!$token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid credentials'], 401);
        }

        $cookie = $this->getCookie($token);

        return response()->json([
            'token' => $token,
            'user' => auth()->user(),
        ])->withCookie($cookie);
    }

    /**
     * Set cookie details and return cookie
     *
     * @param string $token JWT
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Cookie\CookieJar|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie
     */
    private function getCookie($token)
    {
        return cookie(
            env('AUTH_COOKIE_NAME'),
            $token,
            auth()->factory()->getTTL(),
            null,
            null,
            env('APP_DEBUG') ? false : true,
            true,
            false,
            'Strict'
        );
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public function me()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And the code for the handle method in the middleware class(`app/Http/Middleware/AddAuthTokenHeader.php`) used in the custom middleware `auth.api` is

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $cookie_name = env('AUTH_COOKIE_NAME');

    if (!$request->bearerToken()) {
        if ($request->hasCookie($cookie_name)) {
            $token = $request->cookie($cookie_name);

            $request->headers->add([
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token
            ]);
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

As you can see in my `AuthController` once the login request is successfully the json response is sent along with the http-only cookie.

**NOTE**: Am using `php artisan serve` to run my backend

#### FRONT-END

After running `npm run serve` in my `vue-cli` generated project, I go to the `login` route which displays the `Login` component represented by `@/views/Login.vue`.

Here is my code for the `Login.vue`

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <form @submit.prevent="submit" autocomplete="off">
            <p>
                <label for="email">Email: </label>
                <input
                    type="email"
                    name="email"
                    id="email"
                    v-model.lazy="form.email"
                    required
                    autofocus
                />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="password">Password: </label>
                <input
                    type="password"
                    name="password"
                    id="password"
                    v-model.lazy="form.password"
                    required
                />
            </p>
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    name: 'login',
    data() {
        return {
            form: {
                email: '',
                password: '',
            },
        };
    },

    methods: {
        async submit() {
            const url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login';
            const response = await axios.post(url, this.form, {
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            });

            console.log(response);
            // this.$router.replace({ name: 'home' });
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Given valid credentials on route(`http:localhost:8080/login`), the cookie will be returned as seen in the response headers below

[image]

but for some reason, it's not being set in the browser cookie cookie storage as shown below

[image]

**NOTE**: The cookie shown above is from me testing if everything is running fine after running `php artisan serve` and opening `http:localhost:8000` in the browser.

Question is, why isn't the cookie being stored in the browser cookie storage.

*I should note that when I call the same backend api routes using `POSTMAN`, everything works fine(with the cookie being set on login and cleared on logout).*

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP so cannot give a complete answer but my first thought is that you're missing `withCredentials` on the request. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials. By default this is not enabled with axios but you can enable it with `withCredentials: true`. I believe you'll also need to ensure that your server is not using `*` for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: @skirtle Thank you for the tips. Let me try out your recommendations and see how that goes.

Comment: @skirtle I have tried setting `withCredentials: true` in my axios headers and limiting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to calling client side but it's still not working.

Comment: `withCredentials` is not a header. Please check the axios documentation and ensure you are putting it in the correct place.

Comment: @skirtle I managed to solve it thanks to you. Please check out my answer below.

Comment: @kellymandem I am still learning about this approach (storing jwt in cookie) and your question and answer has helped me a lot. I just wonder why you still send a token back to the front end? Also, I guess this method drops the need to have refresh tokens?

Comment: @digout I have not used refresh tokens technique before, so I can't speak with much authority on that but as to the issue of sending the token back to the frontend, I think the reason for that is if you look at the code in the file `app/Http/Middleware/AddAuthTokenHeader.php` you do notice that before any API routes are reached the authorization header is added with the value coming from the cookie in the browser/frontend.

Comment: @kellymandem thanks yeah I noticed that, but both in your finished sample and the tutorial sends the token back in the return response also. Just wondered why.

Comment: @digout I see where you are coming from; I think you are referring to this code `return response()->json(['token' => $token, 'user' => auth()->user(),])->withCookie($cookie);`. In my case I did that so I could possibly use it in my `vuex` code for user authentication but as it turns out, I did not need it.

Comment: It is necessary to set `withCredentials: true` when using XMLHTTPRequest `credentials: true` when using Fetch in the request that expects to receive credentials. This appears to only be the case when the cookie returned sets `httpOnly: true`.

I'm making this note, as I faced a similar issue and ended up on this thread. My issue was that the received cookie was not being stored by Firefox 75.0 nor Google Chrome 81.0.4044.113. I had assumed that the browser would automatically store the cookie and that credentials flag would denote whether the cookie should be used in subsequent requests.

Comment: @errolflynn From my experience so far, it's the only way.

Comment: @kellymandem I noted this because it was difficult for me to find that information in the documentation

Answer (score 8):

All credit to @skirtle for helping me to solve this; your help was invaluable.

Here are the steps I took to make it work.

#### BACKEND

I run the command `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider"` which creates a file `cors.php` under the `config` directory.

I then changed this line `'supportsCredentials' => false,` in `config/cors.php` to `'supportsCredentials' => true,` and I left everything else the same after which I run the following commands just to make sure the new changes were captured.

```sh
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan serve
```

#### FRONTEND

All I had is to change my `submit` method in the `Login.vue` to this

```js
async submit() {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login';
    const response = await axios.post(url, this.form, {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    });

    console.log(response.data);
    // this.$router.replace({ name: 'home' });
},
```

And now the cookie is being set as shown below

[image]

Once again, all thanks and credit to @skirtle the tips.

Answer (score 0):

You can setting `httponly=false` for accessing to cookie on front-end.

Laravel provides an option for this:

```
cookie($name, $value, $minutes = 0, $path = null, $domain = null, $secure = false, $httpOnly = false)
```