# can't setting cookie after login

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I have set 3 virtual hosts as mentioned  below

api.project.test

assets.project.test

project.test

**backend** api.project.test/auth/login, which set cookie as mentioned below

```
   protected function respondWithToken(string $token): JsonResponse
    {
        $expiresIn = auth('api')->factory()->getTTL() * 60;

        return response()
            ->json([
                'access_token' => $token,
                'token_type' => 'bearer',
                'expires_in' => $expiresIn
            ])
            ->withCookie('token', $token, $expiresIn, '/', parse_url(config('app.frontend_url'), PHP_URL_HOST));
    }
```

**frontend** - project.test

**assets** - assets.project.test

ie assets.project.test/filename.ext URL which goes middleware, which checks cookie ie 'token' exists, and it always returns empty.

```
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        
        $token = $request->cookie('token');
        if (empty($token)) {
            abort(404);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: Did you check your browser tools to see if the cookie is actually set? Maybe setting the cookie first and then returning the response will help

Comment: Thank you @brombeer , I tried you suggestion, but did not work.

Later I found this below link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58710013/httponly-cookie-not-being-set-stored-laravel-vue